# Executing AWS Lambda with assumed role with web identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Is it possible for Lambda to be executed via API Gateway with an assumed role on behalf of a Cognito authenticated user?

Right now I'm doing the role assumption manually, from within the Lambda code:

```js
  const assumedRole = await sts.send(new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityCommand({
    RoleArn: 'some role ARN',
    RoleSessionName: event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims['cognito:username'],
    WebIdentityToken: event.headers.authorization
  }));
```

But I would like to avoid that, and have the Lambda be executed with this assumed role already.

What I am having difficulty with is figuring out what IAM Role and policy is required to achieve that.

Thanks!

Comment: This could promote a pretty bad practice. What prevents a malicious user from using their token to assume the role themselves, accessing resources directly and circumventing any validation and sanitization logic?

Comment: The idea is to only allow resources that they need access to via the IAM roles and policy documents.

Comment: The ideal role will have the right policy to access whatever resource you want the user to access and a trust relationship to allow sts:assume role

Answer (score 0):

You can pass cognito token from header of your request to the lambda and then make a get get credentials for identity call. That would be the best approach for assuming role of your cognito user dynamically. If you have configured cognito to grant role based on token you don't even need to explicitely provide a role arn in the call.